# How to fade out elements on delete in MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, fadeout

Take a look at: http://shopping-list.meteor.com. I want to fade out the items when they're deleted instead of having them instantly disappear, and I'm not sure how I'd implement this.

The code is at http://github.com/chintanparikh/shopping-list.

If anyone can set me on the right path, that'd be awesome.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [callback](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/):

```
Template.item.events({
  'click .close': function()
  {
    var self = this;
    $(self).fadeOut('slow', function() { Items.remove(self); });

  }
})
```

Update: added "self" as suggested by Rahul.

Comment: ```
    var id = "#" + this['_id'];
    $(id).fadeOut('slow', function()
      {
        Items.remove(this);   
      });

```

However, for some reason that gives me RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded, and doesn't remove anything

Comment: That's because `this` refers to the callback function. You should refer to the object by eg. `var self = this` or some other method of binding scope.

Comment: The question asked to fadeout the element AFTER the item has been removed from the database. This answer fades the element out before confirmation from the database that the document has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Template.item.events({
  'click .close': function()
  {
    //get parent (li) and fade it out.
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    Items.remove(this);
  }
})
```

Comment: Tried it, no dice. What I'm trying now is adding an id the li with value _id, then selecting that with jQuery, getting it to fadeOut, then removing the item with Item.remove

Comment: @user1045696 Maybe the function is not returning the `li` but the `button`, in which case I  updated the code to fade out the parent.